# Web Server Public ip address to be seen on webpage

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi, ip-address, webpage, dynamic-ip

I have a Raspberry Pi behind NAT running Linux and hosting a web server. I access the web page from outside via Yaler utility as I have Dynamic public ip address. Is there a way to show my current public ip address on the web page? If I get my public ip address, I can access many of the NATted devices in that network. Yaler domain does not resolve to my actual public ip address.

Comment: Doesn't Yaler offer this somehow? Other than that, do you have PHP running on the machine?

Comment: Yaler is based on reverse http and there is no direct mapping between the Yaler domain and my public dynamic ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Either way you'll need some simple script for this.

One easy example would be using DNS lookup.

If you can't use the `host` command, install it using `sudo apt-get install host`.

Then simply run the command `host -t a your.public.domain`. This will result in a line like this:

> your.public.domain has address 12.34.56.78

You'll just have to parse the result, e.g. in PHP you could use something like this:

```
<?php
$ip = 'unknown';
if (preg_match('/has address (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/', exec('host -t a your.public.domain'), $m))
    $ip = $m[1];
echo "The public IP is $ip.";
```

Keep in mind that this will delay code execution by about a second; so you should cache the result.

Comment: IPv6 is sadly still rather uncommon, but I wanted to make a note that in its current for this works for IPv4 only.  Also +1 since it is 99% guaranteed to be the answer the OP as well as most site visitors will be looking for.

Comment: Well, you could probably extend the regular expression to catch IPv6 as well. Unfortunately I don't have a public one so can't test it.

Comment: The Yaler domain does not resolve to my ip address. My session is with Yaler domain and Yaler redirects that session to my ip address via Reverse http.

Comment: @SamirSogay Oh? Okay, so for what do you need your "public" IP then?

Comment: If I have to manage my web server remotely via ssh. Also, getting the public ip address would allow me to access many other devices which are behind the NAT.

Comment: @Samir, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php or `<?php echo file_get_contents('http://ip.appspot.com/'); ?>` might help.

Comment: Arjan: You could post that as a new answer, although that might not necessarily return the correct public IP.

Comment: @Arjan I think your solution is taking me in the right direction. Could you please elaborate how to put this in HTML code as I don't know much about it.

Comment: @SamirSogay You can't do that client side (read: in pure HTML). You'll have to do it server side using some scripting language, since it has to be run by the server. Otherwise it would return the public IP of the user visiting your page rather than the public IP of the server serving that page.

Comment: @Mario I intend to do it on server side i.e. on the webpage of the server

Comment: @Arjan Please add your solution as another answer, I want to mark it correct.